# MultiList not displaying all result from webservice (Codename One)

Tags: java, codenameone

Im trying to display some json records using a MultiList. I followed what was done here https://www.codenameone.com/manual/graphics.html but mine is returning only one record (Please see this [image](https://05360592106309013684.googlegroups.com/attach/2deee0efb9c41/output1.png?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHzxbxpDzP8-d96FzU0q9dWVGc5mWODyJ-ilf0N6vm1eEwB6Taqkkoyak0iAib1iRgRt-XqgXsYudbPTzoG2zx6AV1cHAk15w4MsQQAZ5cs8OtXvkM)). The response came from this [webservice](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Johor+city+point+of+interest&language=en&key=AIzaSyDVw0z5f4MNN-t1zI2N3bBIcWX4D3Kp3mE)

Below is my code. Please kindly show me where i'm wrong.

```
@Override
    protected void beforeFormA(Form f) {        
         Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Button");
         FontImage p = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_PORTRAIT, s);
         EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(p.scaled(p.getWidth() * 3, p.getHeight() * 4), false);
         getattractive();//fetch results from webservice and store inside response variable
         ArrayList arr = (ArrayList) response.get("results");                
                for (Object m:arr){                   
                Map ma = (Map)m;                        
                address =(String) ma.get("formatted_address");
                name=(String)ma.get("name");
                icon=(String)ma.get("icon");
         ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>(); 
         data.add(createListEntry(name,address,icon));                                      
        DefaultListModel<Map<String, Object>> model = new DefaultListModel<>(data);
        MultiList ml = new MultiList(model);
        ml.getUnselectedButton().setIconName("icon_URLImage");
        ml.getSelectedButton().setIconName("icon_URLImage");
        ml.getUnselectedButton().setIcon(placeholder);
        ml.getSelectedButton().setIcon(placeholder);
        f.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, ml);          
      }                    
   }    


private Map<String, Object> createListEntry(String name, String addr, String coverURL) {
    Map<String, Object> entry = new HashMap<>();    
    entry.put("Line1", name);
    entry.put("Line2", addr);
    entry.put("icon_URLImage", coverURL);
    entry.put("icon_URLImageName", name);
    return entry;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the indentation. The for loop encapsulates everything so you are looping over all the elements and for X elements you are adding X multi lists.

This is something you would instantly see if you step over the code with a debugger...

Answer (score 0):

done. I moved the line below out of the method and place it inside the class.

ArrayList> data = new ArrayList<>();